# Maven searches for a sub-module of my project on internet

Tags: java, maven

I have a project with three level of module as following:
root module name is `sipa`. Its pom file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sipa</groupId>
    <artifactId>sipa</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>

    <modules>
        <module>router</module>
    </modules>
```

`Router` is sub-module of `Sipa` and its pom is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>sipa</artifactId>
        <groupId>sipa</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sipa.router</groupId>
    <artifactId>router</artifactId>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>com.router.api</module>
```

Finally `com.router.api` is leaf of `router` module and its pom is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>sipa.router</groupId>
        <artifactId>router</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sipa.router</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.router.api</artifactId>
```

after this description I run `instal` command on `sipa` project and following log shown on shell:

```
D:\sipa>mvn install

D:\sipa>set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/sipa/router/router/1.0.0.0/router-1.0.0.0.pom
```

My question is : What maven search on internet for `router` module? It is a local module on my sipa project?

Answer (score 0):

Your module should have the same `groupId` as the parent if it's included from the parent like that.

Comment: Your means is: all pom must has a group id ?

Comment: No that's not necessary.

Comment: @chrylis I agree with khmarbaise because I solve my problem as following answer.